# Присваивание объектам

Tags: c#

Каким образом сделать присвоение объектам?
Например, есть класс Value, у него есть поле public int v.
Создаем объект Value value = new Value();
Необходимо, чтобы можно было сделать так:
value = 5;
а не делать value.v = 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь ключевым словом [**implicit:**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z5z9kes2.aspx)

```
public class Value
{
    // ...

    public static implicit operator Value(int argument)
    {
        return new Value(argument);
        // Или 'new Value { v = argument }'
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, никогда не слышал об implicit раньше.